# stuck on simplifying step with substitution of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was stuck on this question and found the answer with work on [yahoo answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090215200411AAFkd61).

Question: solve $(x)dx + (y-2x )dy = 0 $ by making the appropriate substitution.

I got to $\ln{|x|} + \frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}+1}+\ln{|\frac{y}{x}+1|}+C=0$ but couldn't quite get to what the answer key had.

From the yahoo answers

> ln | x | = -1/(y/x + 1) - ln|y/x + 1| + C
>
> simplify
>
> ln | x | = -x/(y + x) - ln|(y + x)/x| + C

I don't understand the steps taken between these two equations. Also does anyone have advice on knowing if you have the wrong answer or just the answer key has reworked things a bunch? For example the answer key had something like $\frac{x}{y+x} + \ln{|y + x|} = C$ which doesn't really look like $\ln{|x|} + \frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}+1}+\ln{|\frac{y}{x}+1|}+C=0$

One more question: does "change of variables" and "substitution" refer to the same technique for solving ODEs e.g. for homogeneous equations let y=ux etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:
$$
\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x} + 1} \cdot \frac{x}{x} = \frac{x}{y + x}
$$
and that:
$$
\ln|x| + \ln|\tfrac{y}{x} + 1| = \ln|x(\tfrac{y}{x} + 1)| = \ln|y + x|
$$

Comment: For the first one how did you know to do that step in the sense isn't it a bit subjective whether it's "simpler" or not? Is it that there's one less fraction, because I could just as easily argue two constants were turned into variables which makes it more complicated?

Comment: "Simpler" is certainly subjective. Nevertheless, I would argue that having a single fraction is "simpler" than having fractions within fractions.